# Why can I only change the CSS style through JS only once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Just start to learn JS. I wanna change the fontSize randomly every time I click the button, but it only work the first time I click.

```
var oBox = document.querySelector('#box');
var randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();
var b = document.querySelector('#button');

b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    oBox.style.fontSize = randomNumber + 'px';
})
```

Comment: Move the line that calculates the random number inside the function. Otherwise, how do you expect it to change each time?

Comment: Do you think that every time you use a variable it executes the expression you used in the assignment? That's not how variables work. They just hold a value, not the expression.

Comment: If you only throw a dice _once_, then don't expect that checking what number ended up top multiple times would give different results.

Answer (score 0):

The line `var randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();` is executed only once. Therefore, you should use a constant: `const randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();`.

In your case you have to move this line inside the function. After that, the line will be executed after every click event:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('#box');
const button = document.querySelector('#button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();
    box.style.fontSize = randomNumber + 'px';
});
```

```html
<div id="box">Hello World</div>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

You should also give your JavaScript variables meaningful names. Just `b` is not a good name for more complex software. Also take a look in the documentation for the difference between `let`, `var`, and `const`.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are only generating the random number once. You need to either make a function to generate a different random number every time it's called, like this:

```js
var oBox = document.querySelector('#box');
var b = document.querySelector('#button');

function getRandomNumber() {
  return ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();
}

b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    oBox.style.fontSize = getRandomNumber() + 'px';
})
```

```html
<div id="box">
  This is a test
</div>

<button id="button">
Button
</button>
```

Or to generate it directly in the click event, like this:

```js
var oBox = document.querySelector('#box');
var b = document.querySelector('#button');

b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const randomNumber = ((Math.random() * 10) * 10).toString();
    oBox.style.fontSize = randomNumber + 'px';
})
```

```html
<div id="box">
  This is a test
</div>

<button id="button">
Button
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Making a function to generate is really a better way.

Comment: If you call the function only at one point and the body of the function contains only one line, then a function is unnecessary in my eyes.